# Why does my GIF image not work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

I have a GIF image that I implemented in my app which looks like this:

```
<img src="/images/loader.gif" />
```

I dont know why in Chrome I'm having no problems, but Internet Explorer doesn't show the image.
If you can help me I would appriciate it.
If you need to see more of my code to figure it out, let me know and I will share it.
I guess this question is pretty common and can help a lot of people in the future. :)
Thanks.

Comment: the problem is surely not with that `<img>` tag, please show more of the relevant parts of your page/scripts.

Comment: @Dee Jay: Just a word of advice: spelling mistakes alone shouldn't qualify a question for a down vote. Notice the hover text of the down arrow states "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Sure, this question may also be eligible for a down vote under those conditions, but not because it had spelling mistakes. :)

Comment: Would probably be sensible to show the GIF as well.

Comment: @Dee Jay: As Adam pointed out, spelling mistakes are not a good reason for down votes.  One of the reasons is that this is an international site, for many users, English is not their first language, yet they are required to attempt to use it to get help here.  If they try, so the native speakers should try to be kind.  The correct response is to edit the question to resolve any ambiguities.

Comment: what script do you need to see?

Comment: and dont mind about that jay guy , who cares.

Comment: @Dee Jay: Your comment does not end with a period so that is a grammatical error. I'd be happy to downvote your comment if it were possible. Though I flagged it as rude.

Comment: A live example would probably be most productive.

Comment: @WTP: I downvoted everyone openly and with reason. Rude? Maybe those invisible downvoters deserve that rude tag

Comment: @Dee Jay: The rudeness lies into the fact that you downvote someone's post with such a silly reason they can't do anything about. Also, read the sentence in your bio on your profile page after `2)`.

Comment: @WTP: I'm brutally honest about myself and others. What is your problem?

Comment: @Dee Jay: My problem is that you downvote a post because it contains spelling errors. If that would be a good reason to downvote, 99% of all questions on Stack Overflow would have a score less than -10. Spelling errors simply don't matter on Stack Overflow. If you find a spelling error simply edit the post to fix it if you don't like it the way it is.

Comment: @WTP: You can demand justice on meta

Comment: Might be because Your image has transparency in it ?

Comment: @user804968 make sure the image is RGB & not CMYK - I've had that problem with images sent to me from print shops.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do to troubleshoot would be to create a .html page containing only the `<img>` tag. If this page displays correctly, the problem is elsewhere. If not, you should use the Internet Explorer Tools (F12 in IE 9, I think also in IE 8).